# compute how nice it looks a set of values (how nice is the distribution)

Tags: math, statistics, computer-science, visualization, data-visualization

this set of values:
1 2 3 3 4 1
looks pretty nice if you think of it on a bar chart:

```
*   *
* * * *
=======
1 2 3 4
```

while this one looks bad..
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 8

```
  *
  *
  * 
  * 
  *
  *
  *
* *           * *
=================
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This is because there are a lot of 2 and a big gap between the 2 and the 8...

I need to find a formula which computes how nice a set of number looks..
I think I'll need some deviation function.. any idea?

thanks

Comment: You have an answer in your question - `how nice a set of number looks`. Define a what means `nice` first and write a `nice(list)` function.

Comment: You need to formally define "nice" first.  Does "nice" mean low standard deviation?  Does "nice" mean fits the normal distribution well?  Does it mean the data fit some other distribution well?

Comment: I'm asking for ideas also to define nice.. I provided 2 examples, because I can't define it well in math..

Comment: Nice depends on your motivation and application. Why do you want to know how nice it is?

Comment: This question is almost pure statistics and not CS at all.  :-/

Comment: It's a visualization problem, I have to find out which data is best to visualize among all the data available.

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 3):

A [chi-square analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test) is probably what you're looking for. If used in the right way it will give you a number describing how close your distribution is to a discrete uniform distribution. A discrete uniform distribution will be flat (i.e. have approximately the same number of elements in each of the histogram buckets), which seems to fit your definition of 'nice'.

Answer (score 1):

This seems reasonable to me, but I have pretty limited knowledge of statistics:

```
from collections import Counter
def tonums( s ):
        return [int(x) for x in s if x!=' ']

def nice( nums ):
    # how far do they spread
    used_range = range(min(nums), max(nums)+1)

    # how often would each number occur if they were equally distributed
    expected = 1.0*len(nums)/len(used_range)

    # how often do they actually occur
    counter = Counter(nums)

    # compute the variance
    return sum((count-expected)**2 for item, count in counter.iteritems())


# should be fst < snd
print nice(tonums('1 2 3 3 4 1'))
print nice(tonums('1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 8'))

# these should be 0
print nice(tonums('1'))
print nice(tonums('1 1 1 1'))

# should be equal
print nice(tonums('1 1 2 3'))
print nice(tonums('1 2 2 3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of "nice" is somewhat broad. I'd suggest two approaches to it based on my interpretation of what you mean by nice

1. Compute (or estimate) [how far away from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test) being [normally distributed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36358/are-suggest-a-project-for-me-questions-acceptable) your data is. A stats textbook or stats package should discuss this.
2. Perform some kind of [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) - lot of high frequency components probably aren't "nice".

Comment: A _nicely_ flat distribution has tons of higher order Fourier coefficients.

Comment: @honk, agreed, but Fourier analysis might be useful for some other values of "nice" still